# document.getElementById("someid').innerHTML = "HI"; doesn't work for me

Tags: javascript, dom, timer, scope, getelementbyid

I don't understand how to manipulate the DOM very well.  I have used

```
document.getElementById('someid').innerHTML = "HI";
```

in other places and it works fine.  But when I went to add a timer to my webpage I can't use the above to change some text (the timer).  So... I'm very confused.  You have all helped me in other problems I have had...  I research lots before bugging you all but I'm stumped & frustrated.

**in signupForm.php - SNIPPIT**

```
<title>Perry Computer Services - Signup</title>
<script src="js/commonUtils.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/timers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">window.onload = CreateTimer(30);</script>
```

**in timers.js**

```
function CreateTimer(Time)
{
  alert("Timer created:" + Time);
  document.getElementById('debug1').innerHTML = "WORKS";
  alert("We never get here.");
}
```

**in signupForm.php - SNIPPIT**

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="signupForm.php?calling_page=validateform" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <table border="0" align="center">
    <tr class="table_top">
      <td class="tbl_col1"><div align="right" id="debug1"></div></td>
      <td class="tbl_col2"><div align="left" id="debug2"></div></td>
```

Here's what I'm confused about.  I have another .js file called validation.js and I use the exact same document.getElementById as above in there and it works!!!  I don't get it!

In validation.js I modify the DOM a lot and it works great!   Is it working because when I change a field by tabbing to the next field ***is this a SCOPE problem?***  If someone doesn't know what I'm doing wrong I'll try to chop up my validation.js and stick it in here but it's huge.  Why would 1 function work and another one in a different file not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call `CreateTimer` **immediately** and assign its return value (`undefined`) to `onload`.

At the time you call it, the element with the specified ID does not exist, and that line errors and stops the script from running any further.

Assign a **function** to onload.

```
 window.onload = function () { CreateTimer(30); };
```

Comment: wow, that was fast.  I'll try that now...   It worked!   Thank you VERY much!  I should have just asked here but I like to try and solve it myself by reading.  But after so many hours scratching my head you solved it in seconds.  Thank you!

Comment: No, headscratching first is the proper procedure :) That way you actually get to learn stuff. People who ask without the requisite headscratching never rise above mediocrity...

Comment: I have a followup question if you can help with it.   Why would the alerts work but the document.getElementById not work?  Doesn't onload mean wait till everything is loaded THEN do something?  Oops... I see a response below!

Comment: I agree with you on the head scratching 1st, questions 2nd.  You learn lots struggling to find the answer which is why I try first.  I haven't programmed in 17+ years!  I mastered 6502 Assembly Language on the Commodore 64.  This is my first project in almost 2 decades & it's huge.  Sometimes I think I am in over my head.  I just find it frustrating when I read how something is supposed to work.. and doesn't really work that way!  lol.  You all have helped me fix some very confusing things from UTF-8 mess and now this!   Much appreciated helping this old brain learn something new! :)

Comment: @PerryCS — Onload does mean that, but as I said on the first line of my answer, you aren't actually using it.

Answer (score 1):

It is a timing issue. Notice that the page is blank at the time of the alert, and also notice that if you run your command from the console afterwards everything works okay. You are trying to modify the element that is not loaded yet. The reason for that is the fact that onload is not set up properly - you're calling CreateTimer before the proper time.

When you have these kinds of problems, trying to isolate which part of the huge line is the issue would help. For instance:

```
alert("Timer created:" + Time);
alert(document.getElementById('debug1'));
alert(document.getElementById('debug1').innerHTML);
```

Also, using `console.log()` instead of `alert()` will also save you some frustration.

Comment: Thank you!   I was under the impression that onload had everything ready.  During trying to figure this out I read many documents about waiting for the DOM to be ready and not using onload.   I also never heard of console.log() - I'll have to look that up!  Thank you!  alerts are annoying!  lol